# "Increment" a created type

Tags: types, ocaml, increment

I'm trying to implement a cards game in OCaml.

```
type rank = Three | Four | Five | Six;;
```

(I simplified) My question is :
Is it possible from a rank (for example Four) to access the following/previous one? (Five/Three)

I tested some things and saw that we can compare with `compare > < =` different ranks. So knowing that the order exists, maybe the incrementation process is possible for a rank?

(If there is no solution i can do a function with a big match with and tell what to return for each rank but if a fastest solution exists...)

Comment: If you need to do math then it would probably be better to make a type that wraps an integer. Or write a function that converts integers to / from your type.

Comment: fine so there is no trivial way to do it?

Comment: I gave you the trivial way to do it: write a function that converts to integers.  "Trivial" means "I know how to do it".  Now, if you want to write an increment then you're going to have to say what the increment of `Six` is.

Comment: Yes sorry haha I wrote my comment admiting that your first solution was the "optimal" one, I actually decided to write a function as I described in an answer of this topic. Thanks you for the answers!

Comment: Note that the OCaml documentation describes the representation of types should you decide to access them from C code. An ugly answer to your question would therefore be to write a C function that gets a rank and returns a rank. With the current description of the representation of types, this function could be written as a C addition, with an additional test for safety. An even uglier shortcut would be to use the module `Obj`, but that is not documented, so I would stick to writing C code against the documented interfaces. (No actually do not do either)

Comment: Can't really use C with the constraints I have but it is actually an interesting shortcut (let's not be be ugly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ppx_deriving](https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving) to define an enumerated type with easy access to underlying integer values.

**Update**

I've never used ppx_deriving, so I thought I'd try it out. Here's a little code that works for me:

```
type cards = Five [@value 5] | Six | Seven [@@deriving enum]

let apply_enum fn card =
    match cards_of_enum (fn (cards_to_enum card)) with
    | None -> failwith "apply_enum: no such value"
    | Some p -> p

let predecessor card = apply_enum (fun x -> x - 1) card
let successor card = apply_enum ((+) 1) card
```

Comment: im working without external sources but this looks really interesting for my personnal knowing and eventually for a future project thanks

Comment: There's no built-in mechanism for predecessor/successor functions. I've often wished for them in fact. It's complicated by non-nullary constructors. For example, what is the successor of `None` or the predecessor of `Some true`?

Comment: Yes I asked myself about this issue but when i saw that comparators were working idk I thought maybe it could exists but yes it's obvious that there would be issues and so it is logical that there's no built in mechanism. However thanks for the help and the bit of explanation!

Answer (score 0):

So we are a bit forced to use integers, and my type does not have so much possibilities, so I decided to do a function rankToInt which to each rank associates an int. I dont really need more for what I have to do, but I understand that the better solution solution would be to define a type rank which includes an integer valueos that we dont have to call a function like rankToInt everytime.